# Pre-install Script for package

Tags: apex, salesforcedx, managed-package, integration, installedpackage

I am creating a package for integration purpose. I want to show a screen as pre-install configurations, where users can add few required information after that the user will get authorized via backend API call. If authorization got failed then we will not allow him to install Package at all. Currently this is just an idea. I am here to discuss this with you guys, that is this implementation is possible within salesforce?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can only run Salesforce components of any type after installation. If you really want this sort of pre-install check, set a password to prohibit installs, and then set up a public site where the user has to go through the required steps, and then initiate a metadata deploy request to their org after the required steps. You can use a Connected App to get an active session and verify that they have install privileges. Note that this hypothetical code wouldn't allow direct installs from the AppExchange; you'd configure your listing to redirect to your site for registration.

Comment: Thanks @sfdcfox this is really helpful, let me try this.